# Computing the sum of all measures for a certain group type

Tags: javascript, performance, typescript

I have a method that receives 2 params:

- first one is an array of objects of type { group1: string, group2: string, measure: number, ... }
- second one is a string

I also have an *enum* **GroupColumns**

```
enum GroupColumns {
  ColumnTypeX = 'Column Type X',
  ColumnTypeY = 'Column Type Y',
  ColumnTypeZ = 'Column Type Z'
}
```

This method computes the sum of all the measures for a certain group type when the second parameter matches the second group and the first group is equal to any group found in GroupColumns enum.

```js
    private ComputeSpecificColumnMeasure(data: Array<IDynamic<any>>, groupType: String): number {
        let measure: number = 0;
        data.forEach(el => {
            if (el.group2 === groupType && (el.group1 === GroupColumns.ColumnTypeX || el.group1 === GroupColumns.ColumnTypeY || el.group1 === GroupColumns.ColumnTypeZ )) {
                measure += el.measure;
            }
        });

        return measure;
    }
```

I do not like the verifications inside the if. If I somehow want to add more columns(unlikely) I would need to expand it, or create another method only to check if group1 is equal to any GroupColumns.

Any opinions?

How can I make this code scalable and optimized

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Since the majority of developers want their code to be *scalable* and *optimized*, the current question title, applies to too many posts on this site. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as  [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/120114) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/250666/revisions#rev-arrow-58d41dbb-de09-4b8a-b9c1-66ac6eacaa2d) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If possible, I'd change the `GroupColumns` to be an array instead. That way, all you need to do is use `.includes` to see if an item is included in it. Other improvements can be:

**Let TS automatically infer types when possible**. You only need to denote the type of a variable or the type of a return value when TS can't do so on its own. TS can automatically determine that `ComputeSpecificColumnMeasure` returns a number. It can also determine that `measure` will be a number, so there's no need to denote the type of either of those.

**Avoid String type** The "String" type is something created via the String constructor, eg `const str = new String('data');`. This is almost never what you want - for a normal string, use the `string` (primitive) type instead. (TSLint rule: [`ban-types`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/ban-types/))

**Avoid `any`** You have `data: Array<IDynamic<any>>`. `any` should be avoided in TypeScript whenever possible, because it's so flexible - it loses type safety. If you don't know what the type will be, use `unknown` instead, which is type-safe.

For a small example of a problem with `any`:

```
const fn = (arg: any) => {
    console.log(arg.toFixed(2));
}
```

This will not throw a TS error, but it's likely to throw a runtime error unless the argument passed happens to be a number. Using `unknown` instead *will* throw a TS error - it'll force you to narrow the type first before calling a particular method on it.

```
const fn = (arg: unknown) => {
    if (typeof arg === 'number') {
        console.log(arg.toFixed(2));
    }
}
```

Even if the value that's `any` isn't being used in the function, it'd good practice to avoid `any` when possible anyway. (TSLint rule: [`no-unsafe-any`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-unsafe-any/))

**Capitalization** Conventionally, only a *few things* use PascalCase in JS:

- Namespaces (eg `React`)
- Classes
- Enums, sometimes

A plain method should probably use the standard `camelCase` instead.

```
const groupColumns = [
    'Column Type X',
    'Column Type Y',
    'Column Type Z'
] as const; // Use "as const" to prevent automatic widening to `string[]`

private computeSpecificColumnMeasure(data: Array<IDynamic<unknown>>, groupType: string) {
    let measure = 0;
    data.forEach(el => {
        if (el.group2 === groupType && groupColumns.includes(el.group1)) {
            measure += el.measure;
        }
    });
    return measure;
}
```

Or, you could use `.filter` and `reduce` if you wished:

```
private computeSpecificColumnMeasure(data: Array<IDynamic<unknown>>, groupType: string) {
    return data
        .filter(el => el.group2 === groupType && groupColumns.includes(el.group1))
        .reduce((measureSoFar, el) => measureSoFar + el.measure, 0);
}
```

Comment: Just to expand, if it is needed to be enum (in other places maybe), one can use `Object.keys(GroupColumns).map(k => GroupColumns[k]).includes(group)`, but ofc, best to prepare the array before the loop...